# Error: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, None, None, 224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to create a model that can detect balloons by creating a CNN model. When I try to `fit()` the model I get this error:
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(None, None, None, 224, 224, 3)`

I have tried making some changes (primarily small changes) but nothing really worked. I don't know what can cause that so anything will be helpful.

### My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

annotations_file = '/content/balloon-data.csv'
annotations = pd.read_csv(annotations_file)

image_paths = []
labels = []
for i, row in annotations.iterrows():
    if row['num_balloons'] > 0:
        image_path = 'path/to/image/{}'.format(row['fname'])
        image_paths.append(image_path)
        labels.append(1)
    else:
        image_path = 'path/to/image/{}'.format(row['fname'])
        image_paths.append(image_path)
        labels.append(0)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths, labels))

def preprocess_image(image_path, label):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (224, 224))
    image = image / 255.0
    return image, label

dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: preprocess_image(x, y)).batch(64)

train_size = int(0.8 * len(image_paths))
test_size = len(image_paths) - train_size
train_dataset = dataset.take(train_size)
test_dataset = dataset.skip(train_size)

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(32)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(32)

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(64)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(64)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=test_dataset)
```

### **Edit**

Changes:

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: preprocess_image(x, y)).batch(64) 
#changed to 
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_image)

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(64)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(64)
#Were deleted
```

Comment: You only batch tf.data once, not three times.

Comment: Remove all .batch(something) and just do it once on each dataset. For example, on training dataset, you now get 64 batches os 32 batches of 64 batches of images.